# JavaFX - static method to modify Stage/Node from another class Good or Bad practice?

Tags: java, javafx

Closing login window from another class

```
public class Login{

      public static Login instance;
      public static LoginButton;

      public Login(){
      instance = this;
      LoginButton = new Button("Log In");
      }

public static void  closeLogin(){
     instance.getStage().dispose();
     }
```

// modify button

```
 public static disableButton(){
 LoginButton.disable(true);
 }

 }

 }
```

// Trigger closeLogin() and disableButton() from another class

```
public class AnotherClass{
private Button button;

public AnotherClass(){
button = new Button("Close Login"); 

    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
    public void handle(Event e) {

        Login.closeLogin(); // close the Login Window
        Login.disableButton();  // disable Button from Login Window

    }
});

}

}
```

Is this approach is a good practice?

if not can you give me some code how to do it.

Comment: Not really. Use a DI framework of some sort - inject a singleton instance.